# How do I view the latest commits of a remote Git repository without making a clone first?

Tags: git, commit

I want to get a list of the latest commits on a certain remote Git repository. However, I do not want to create a clone because that takes too long.

With SVN, I can simply pass along a username and password. With Git I haven't found an option to do this. Also, is there an XML output option like with SVN?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994004/git-getting-info-about-a-change-without-a-local-repository  . Other answer suggests using `git ls-history {url}` to lookup the available tags and branches and their latest commit id's to check if a new commit has been made to a branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not exactly what you want, but you could create a *shallow* clone using the `--depth` option to [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone). That clones only the last *n* revisions. It still copies all the content, though.

For XML-like formatting you could use a [custom log format](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) like this:

```
git log --pretty=format:'<commit><author>%ae</author><subject>%s</subject></commit>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch from the remote repository.  This does not merge the changes into your local code, but is represented locally by a branch for the remote repository, with the latest commits.

I.e., you can see individual commits to the remote repository and even cherry-pick single commits if you want.