# Git: getting info about a change without a local repository?

Tags: git

My program has remote access to a git repository over ssh, and sometimes needs to get information (like commit message) about particular git commits.  How can I query a remote git repository for this kind of information, without having a local clone of the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could *probably* do this, by emulating a lot of operation git already does internal and by heavy manual usage of the git *plumbing* (low-level) commands. However if you do that, you not only need to a lot of really low-level things yourself, you also will end up with very little efficiency in what you do (not only if you request information for a second time).

So I would suggest you to just do a (high-level) clone from the repository and work with it that way, even if that repository will only exist temporary. If you only want to look at the newest commits for example, you can easily restrict what you clone by creating a *shallow* clone (use the `--depth` option with clone).

Comment: The thing to note is that once you make your initial clone, subsequent bandwidth usage (from fetching) is minimal. Don't be scared off by the idea of a clone - it's an investment followed by a little upkeep, not a large continuing cost. Your clone can also be bare - no work tree!

Answer (score 5):

I only know of [git ls-remote](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html) to lookup the available tags and branches and their latest commit id's. You could use that to check if a new commit has been made to a branch.

Comment: `ls-remote` still requires you to have a (local) repository that has a reference to the remote. And to get actual updated information, you need to fetch from that repository first, and then there is no difference to a completely cloned local repository.

Comment: @poke: Not true. `git ls-remote <url>` works without a repository. True, though, those refnames and SHA1s may not do you a ton of good.

Comment: You can just call `ls-remote` on a remote repository without having to fetch it first. However, if you want something like the log messages you still need to fetch a local copy as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ssh remote command execution to execute arbitrary git commands

> $ssh user@host "cd path/to/repo && git log"

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the repository host's API, if you are hosting with [Github](https://developer.github.com/), [Bitbucket](http://restbrowser.bitbucket.org/), or similar.