# Is there a way to pull just the commit messages from a remote repository?

Tags: git, message, git-clone

I've got a script that basically analyzes the commit messages in a given remote repository.

My current implementation clones the remote repository, then iterates through each branch, running the "git whatchanged" command.

If all I need are the commit messages, is there any way I could go about doing so without having to clone the repository? I think this would speed the script up considerably.

Comment: This might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994004/git-getting-info-about-a-change-without-a-local-repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that `git` provides a mechanism for remotely iterating over a repository.  If you keep a cached working directory locally, so that instead of re-cloning the entire you're simply applying updates, then you shouldn't have speed problems.

If your remote repository happens to be on `github`, then they have a remote HTTP [API](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/) for interacting with a repository that may make what you describe possible.