# GIT: browsing across the repositories

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisesvn

I'm switching to GIT after 10 years of SVN experience, i'm looking for something to browse trough the repository like i was doing with SVN through the browser (httpd) or with tools like Tortoise.

I know that because GIT is a distributed repository, probably this is less crucial need, but by my prospective it is.

I would like to avoid the httpd option cause it forces me to do some changes/configs to the GIT server which i would like to avoid.

I'm trying to find a solution with very low impacts, any suggestions?

There are some duplicates of this question:

- [git - browse remote repos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26062467/git-browse-remote-repos)
- [git repository browsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082909/git-repository-browsing)
- [Git - Browse remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779054/git-browse-remote-repository)

But I'm not looking for a git feature which I know is not there, but for a external tool that allow me to do something like this.

Obviously i'm talking about my company repositories and not public, so solution like git hub/git lab would not be an option.

Thanks

Comment: Try `git instaweb`, https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-instaweb. Besides, you can run a Gitlab or Gerrit server to host your company repositories. But they are not lightweight.

Comment: [Git GUIs](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis). Both GitHub and GitLab have locally-installable versions; GitLab CE is free.