# Retrieve latest git commit hash of a Github repository without cloning

Tags: git, github, github-api

Is it possible to remotely retrieve the latest commit hash of a Github repo without cloning it locally? I'm referring to something like the following you see at the top of all the repos in Github:

[image: Github Latest Commit]

Based on some older [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068494/how-do-i-view-the-latest-commits-of-a-remote-git-repository-without-making-a-clo) it seems that this may not be possible with `git` directly (unless there's a new feature that enables it), <s>so the right answer might involve using the Github API</s> (turns out Github API won't work for my use case since I'll have to use a different set of credentials then the private key `git` uses).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the last commit ID of a remote repo using curl-like command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176359/how-to-get-the-last-commit-id-of-a-remote-repo-using-curl-like-command)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the last commit hash from a remote repo without cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750215/getting-the-last-commit-hash-from-a-remote-repo-without-cloning)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19176736/47110) thanks to @jszakmeister:

```
git ls-remote $URL HEAD
```

For my private repo, I had to use the following syntax instead of the URL:

```
git ls-remote git@github.com:ORG/PROJECT.git HEAD
```